# DOM is not updating when data variable changes in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to update an array of arrays and rendering it as a reactive variable, but DOM is not reflecting those changes.

For doing this, I'm using 2 components, a parent and a child one:

**Parent component**
Instanciates child component and passes a method (fetchOptionsFn) as a prop, which fetches some data and updates an array located in child component

```
<component :is="DynamicDataPairForm"
            :fetchOptionsFn="fetchOptionsFn"

fetchOptionsFn (search, loading, selectOptionsArray, index) {
      if (search.length >= 3) {
        pptDocumentLibraryService.findByTitle(search).then(res => {
          selectOptionsArray[index] = res.data
        }).catch(err => console.log(err))
      }
```

**Child component**
Defines an empty array, defines a SELECT in the DOM and when a search on it is done, this array is modified by the parent inherited function.

```
<tr v-for="(entity,index) in filteredEntityList" :key="entity[entityIdField]">
<v-select
:options="selectEntityArray[index]"
@search="(search, loading) => {
fetchSelectEntityOptions(search, loading, index) }"
/>
</tr>

props: {
 fetchOptionsFn: { type: Function, required: false, default: () => {} },
},
data: {
 selectEntityArray: []
},
methods: {
 fetchSelectEntityOptions (search, loading, index) {
      this.fetchOptionsFn(search, loading, this.selectEntityArray, index)
    }
}
```

The problem comes when this funcion is called (fetchSelectEntityOptions), but the array (selectEntityArray) doesn't change in DOM.

[image]
[image]

Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the version of Vue you are using ?

Comment: Version 2.6 @MichalLevý

Answer (score 1):

Vue 2 has some [Change Detection Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) you should know...

> Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array:
>
> 1. When you directly set an item with the index, e.g. `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`
> 2. When you modify the length of the array, e.g. `vm.items.length = newLength`

So you need to change the line:

```js
selectOptionsArray[index] = res.data
```

to:

```js
Vue.set(selectOptionsArray, index, res.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you might need to define an `index` data property in the child component otherwise I'm not sure what/which `index` is being referred to in the `:options="selectEntityArray[index]"` attribute.
Then you also need to set the index in the fetchSelectEntityOptions function.

So, maybe something like this:

```
<v-select
:options="selectEntityArray[index]"
@search="(search, loading) => {
fetchSelectEntityOptions(search, loading, index) }"
/>

props: {
 fetchOptionsFn: { type: Function, required: false, default: () => {} },
},
data: {
 selectEntityArray: [],
 index: null,
},
methods: {
 fetchSelectEntityOptions (search, loading, index) {
      this.index = index;
      this.fetchOptionsFn(search, loading, this.selectEntityArray, index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry the code was not complete, index entity is obteines from a v-for loop. @InvisibleGorilla